# Cursor jumping issue in contenEditable field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cursor, highlight, contenteditable

The issue that I'm trying to solve has to do with highlighting words in contentEditable html field, or really any rich text editor.

I have a field with some text. The content of that field is being sent to the server to check for grammar issues (or other stuff). Server then responds with a list of words that should be highlighted. For highlighting I am using https://markjs.io/.

The problem is that when response from the server comes back and user is still typing, after highlighting is done, browser does not know where the cursor should be, and it randomly changes position.

```
jsfiddle.net/7n0vvwop/2/
```

Type the word that it supposed to highlight. You will see the jump. In this case I'm using tinymce editor, but the issue persists everywhere.

Does anyone have ideas/thoughts/suggestions ?

Comment: give us more details about your tryings - code samples with detailed description should be enough.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7n0vvwop/2/ type the word that it supposed to highlight. You will see the jump.